# An Elastic search deletebyquery equivalent to this mysql query "delete from item_img where datediff(now(), date) > 5"

Tags: mysql, node.js, elasticsearch

please am searching for an Elastic search deleteByQuery equivalent to this mysql query "delete from item_img where datediff(now(), date) > 5"

here is my code but it doesn't work

```
function osas(){`enter code here`


  client.deleteByQuery({
      index: 'lostit',
      type: 'string',
      body: {
       "query": {
       "range" : {
       "date" : {
        "gt": "now+20m"
                }
               }
            }

          }
     }, function(err, res) {

    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('Indexes have been deleted!');
    }
});
    }
   osas();
```

//It is written based on a nodejs connector to elasticearch

Comment: i know the sample mysql query deletes data that is 5 days old and on my nodejs code i intend to delete data 5days old too

Answer (score 0):

i think i figured it out anyways..using the concept of an inequality equation in math

```
function osas(){`enter code here`


  client.deleteByQuery({
      index: 'lostit',
      type: 'string',
      body: {
       "query": {
       "range" : {
       "date" : {
        "lte": "now-5d"
                }
               }
            }

          }
     }, function(err, res) {

    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('Indexes have been deleted!');
    }
});
    }
   osas();
```